# Palindrome Service Class and Client Class

Tags: java, palindrome

I have several questions I need help with.

I'll add both my code and source code (I guess what assignment asks for clarification) in here.

Service Class

```
public class Palindrome
{    
   private String pal;

    public Palindrome()
    {
       pal = " ";
    }

    public Palindrome(String newPal)
    {          
        pal = newPal.toUpperCase();         
    }

    public void setPal(String initPalin)
    {
       pal = initPalin.toUpperCase();           
    }

    public String getPal()
    {
       return pal;
    }

    public boolean isPalindrome()
    {
       int left = 0;
        int right = pal.length() -1;

        while (pal.equals(toUpperCase))
        {
          if (pal.charAt(left) != pal.charAt(right));
             {
                 return false;
              }
              left++;
              right--;
        }
           return true;
        }

     public String toString()
     {
        return "Palindrome" + isPalindrome();
     }
}
```

Client Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Palindromeclient
    {
      public static void main(String[]args)
      {             
          String pal;
          boolean isS = false;

          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.println("Enter statement press[enter]:");
          String userinput = scan.nextLine();
          Palindrome statement = new Palindrome(pal);

          isS = statement.isPalindrome();

          if (isS)
              System.out.println(userinput + "is a palindrome");              
          else 
              System.out.println(userinput + "is not a palindrome");              
      }      
    }
```

My coding is giving me a

```
Palindrome.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
        while (pal.equals(toUpperCase))
                          ^
  symbol:   variable toUpperCase
  location: class Palindrome
1 error
```

I don't get why though, can I simply add uppercase to the set or second constructor instead, which might be able to fix my service class.

That's my question, number one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to question 1:

`toUpperCase` is a method of the String and should be invoked as one.

```
pal.toUpperCase()
```

Just like you did in the `setPal` method.

Answer to question 2:
The boolean in the main method is not needed, because you could ask your Palindrome object if it is a palidrome directly in de System.out.

```
statement.isPalindrome()
```

Beware though, your program won't work as you don't pass the user input to the Palindrome Constructor.